# Reading url from xml datasource returns 404 not found

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I have an xml data source which has been bound to a grid view. The data is being represented in the grid view fine BUT one of the columns contains a list of url which I want to navigate to. I have tried using template field> item template> `<asp:hyperlink>` (I.e `navigateurl=<%bind ("links")%>` ) but this creates an error because instead of navigating to the url in the xml file it gets routed through the local host (xml file location).

I have also tried binding the column through a label but that just binds the list of url as plain text and not a clickable link.

I think I either need to convert the label into url format or change the routing of the hyperlink datasource somehow. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the code:

```
 <asp:GridView ID="gv1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowSorting="true">
        <Columns>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblid" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("id") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Site Name">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblSiteName" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("Name") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>                       
       
             <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Management Link">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:HyperLink ID="hlManagement" Target="_blank" runat="server" Text="Click" NavigateUrl='<%# Bind("Link", "{0}") %>'></asp:HyperLink>                     
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField> 

        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

and how I am data binding in the code behind:

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.ReadXml(Server.MapPath("~/XML Docs/Sites.xml"));
gv1.DataSource = ds;
gv1.DataBind();
```

And this is the xml snippet:

```
<SiteLink>
    <id> 1 </id>
    <Name> Google </Name>
    <Link> http://www.google.com </Link>
 </SiteLink>
```

The error is: HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found. The routing is: `http://localhost:6482/ http:/www.google.com`, which is where I think the error arise

Comment: Not sure what your XML looks like, but here is a little example that should get you on your way http://www.cstruter.com/blog/309

Comment: Hi Welcome to SO. Your question is not clear. Please include a full example of the code you've written. It's likely worth having a look though the [help] to help you formulate a better question

Comment: I have updated the OP to show how I have implemented the databound XML file.

Comment: Does your real XML have those spaces around the Link value? What happens when you remove them?

Comment: @HansKesting Ooops just checked and you are right, left a space in my xml *doh*. Removing the space on the url has fixed the problem.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Maybe it is irrelevant but google has https protocol, so you should change it to `https://google.com`

Answer (score 0):

I created a Gridview and did a databind with an identical xml file. I changed a couple of things with your Hyperlink control and it worked just fine. It did not append http://localhost in front of the URL.

Let me know if this worked for you, and if it didn't I'll show you my test example that worked.

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="hlManagement" Target="_blank" runat="server" Text="Click"  NavigateUrl='<%# Bind("Link","{0}") %>'></asp:HyperLink>
```

Comment: Same issue unfortunately. even with the modified code; if i click the link instead of redirecting me to www.google.com I get the page not found error. The physical path maps to my c: to the VS project and the requested url reads: http://localhost:6482/ http:/www.google.com.

Any more ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help, problem solved; the spaces in the xml file caused the problem... talk about not being able to see the wood for the trees!